# How to exclude specific data in Access Query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am looking at Receipt line item details and am having an issue excluding specific transactions due to the criteria they include. I have a transaction that has voided items in the transaction and I need to exclude the entire transaction in my data. For Example:

```
                Transaction_id     void_ind   
1   2   1430    12/20/2017  5066    3   2.37    614 N  
1   2   1430    12/20/2017  5066    3   2.37    614 N  
1   2   1430    12/20/2017  5066    3   2.37    614 N  
1   2   1430    12/20/2017  5066    3   2.37    614 N  
1   2   1430    12/20/2017  5066    3   2.37    614 Y  
1   2   1430    12/20/2017  5066    3   2.37    614 Y  
1   2   1430    12/20/2017  5066    3   2.37    614 Y  
1   2   1430    12/20/2017  5066    3   2.37    614 N  
1   2   1430    12/20/2017  5066    3   2.37    614 Y  
1   2   1430    12/20/2017  5066    3   2.37    614 N  
1   2   1430    12/20/2017  5066    3   2.37    614 Y
```

The transaction number is 5066 and each row is a specific item on the receipt. The Y and N shows if that item was voided or not.

What I need to do is exclude this entire transaction from my data. The headers I have included are the correct field names.

This is the SQL now:

```
SELECT BIGPDATAVIEW_TRANSACTION_HEADER.transaction_type_cd,
       BIGPDATAVIEW_TRANSACTION_HEADER.transaction_status_cd,
       BIGPDATAVIEW_TRANSACTION_HEADER.location_id,
       BIGPDATAVIEW_TRANSACTION_HEADER.transaction_dt,
       BIGPDATAVIEW_TRANSACTION_HEADER.transaction_id,
       BIGPDATAVIEW_TRANSACTION_HEADER.workstation_id,
       BIGPDATAVIEW_TRANSACTION_TOTAL.total_transaction_amt,
       BIGPDATAVIEW_RETAIL_TRANSACTION.transaction_duration_nbr,
       BIGPDATAVIEW_RETAIL_TRANSACTION_LINE_ITEM.void_ind
FROM ((BIGPDATAVIEW_TRANSACTION_HEADER
       INNER JOIN BIGPDATAVIEW_RETAIL_TRANSACTION ON (BIGPDATAVIEW_TRANSACTION_HEADER.location_id = BIGPDATAVIEW_RETAIL_TRANSACTION.location_id)
       AND (BIGPDATAVIEW_TRANSACTION_HEADER.transaction_dt = BIGPDATAVIEW_RETAIL_TRANSACTION.transaction_dt)
       AND (BIGPDATAVIEW_TRANSACTION_HEADER.transaction_id = BIGPDATAVIEW_RETAIL_TRANSACTION.transaction_id)
       AND (BIGPDATAVIEW_TRANSACTION_HEADER.workstation_id = BIGPDATAVIEW_RETAIL_TRANSACTION.workstation_id))
      INNER JOIN BIGPDATAVIEW_TRANSACTION_TOTAL ON (BIGPDATAVIEW_TRANSACTION_HEADER.location_id = BIGPDATAVIEW_TRANSACTION_TOTAL.location_id)
      AND (BIGPDATAVIEW_TRANSACTION_HEADER.transaction_dt = BIGPDATAVIEW_TRANSACTION_TOTAL.transaction_dt)
      AND (BIGPDATAVIEW_TRANSACTION_HEADER.transaction_id = BIGPDATAVIEW_TRANSACTION_TOTAL.transaction_id)
      AND (BIGPDATAVIEW_TRANSACTION_HEADER.workstation_id = BIGPDATAVIEW_TRANSACTION_TOTAL.workstation_id))
INNER JOIN BIGPDATAVIEW_RETAIL_TRANSACTION_LINE_ITEM ON (BIGPDATAVIEW_RETAIL_TRANSACTION.location_id = BIGPDATAVIEW_RETAIL_TRANSACTION_LINE_ITEM.location_id)
AND (BIGPDATAVIEW_RETAIL_TRANSACTION.transaction_dt = BIGPDATAVIEW_RETAIL_TRANSACTION_LINE_ITEM.transaction_dt)
AND (BIGPDATAVIEW_RETAIL_TRANSACTION.transaction_id = BIGPDATAVIEW_RETAIL_TRANSACTION_LINE_ITEM.transaction_id)
AND (BIGPDATAVIEW_RETAIL_TRANSACTION.workstation_id = BIGPDATAVIEW_RETAIL_TRANSACTION_LINE_ITEM.workstation_id)
WHERE (((BIGPDATAVIEW_TRANSACTION_HEADER.transaction_type_cd)="1")
       AND ((BIGPDATAVIEW_TRANSACTION_HEADER.transaction_status_cd)="2")
       AND ((BIGPDATAVIEW_TRANSACTION_HEADER.location_id)=1430)
       AND ((BIGPDATAVIEW_TRANSACTION_HEADER.transaction_dt)=#12/20/2017#)
       AND ((BIGPDATAVIEW_TRANSACTION_HEADER.transaction_id)=5066)
       AND ((BIGPDATAVIEW_TRANSACTION_TOTAL.total_transaction_amt)>0
            AND (BIGPDATAVIEW_TRANSACTION_TOTAL.total_transaction_amt)<10)
       AND ((BIGPDATAVIEW_RETAIL_TRANSACTION.transaction_duration_nbr)>500));
```

If someone could help with this it would help so much. Thanks in advance.

Comment: void_ind is a Yes/No field or text type? Something like: `WHERE ... AND NOT Transaction_id IN (SELECT Transaction_id FROM Table WHERE void_ind=True);`

Comment: Yes void_ind is a Yes/No field. I will try this and let you know how it works

Answer (score 0):

Because one of your criteria states that the Transaction ID must be 5066, you are not seeing any results.  you will have to remove that criteria, and exclude the ID numbers of the transactions that you want to exclude in the criteria instead.

Try this:

```
SELECT BIGPDATAVIEW_TRANSACTION_HEADER.transaction_type_cd,
   BIGPDATAVIEW_TRANSACTION_HEADER.transaction_status_cd,
   BIGPDATAVIEW_TRANSACTION_HEADER.location_id,
   BIGPDATAVIEW_TRANSACTION_HEADER.transaction_dt,
   BIGPDATAVIEW_TRANSACTION_HEADER.transaction_id,
   BIGPDATAVIEW_TRANSACTION_HEADER.workstation_id,
   BIGPDATAVIEW_TRANSACTION_TOTAL.total_transaction_amt,
   BIGPDATAVIEW_RETAIL_TRANSACTION.transaction_duration_nbr,
   BIGPDATAVIEW_RETAIL_TRANSACTION_LINE_ITEM.void_ind
FROM ((BIGPDATAVIEW_TRANSACTION_HEADER
   INNER JOIN BIGPDATAVIEW_RETAIL_TRANSACTION ON (BIGPDATAVIEW_TRANSACTION_HEADER.location_id = BIGPDATAVIEW_RETAIL_TRANSACTION.location_id)
   AND (BIGPDATAVIEW_TRANSACTION_HEADER.transaction_dt = BIGPDATAVIEW_RETAIL_TRANSACTION.transaction_dt)
   AND (BIGPDATAVIEW_TRANSACTION_HEADER.transaction_id = BIGPDATAVIEW_RETAIL_TRANSACTION.transaction_id)
   AND (BIGPDATAVIEW_TRANSACTION_HEADER.workstation_id = BIGPDATAVIEW_RETAIL_TRANSACTION.workstation_id))
  INNER JOIN BIGPDATAVIEW_TRANSACTION_TOTAL ON (BIGPDATAVIEW_TRANSACTION_HEADER.location_id = BIGPDATAVIEW_TRANSACTION_TOTAL.location_id)
  AND (BIGPDATAVIEW_TRANSACTION_HEADER.transaction_dt = BIGPDATAVIEW_TRANSACTION_TOTAL.transaction_dt)
  AND (BIGPDATAVIEW_TRANSACTION_HEADER.transaction_id = BIGPDATAVIEW_TRANSACTION_TOTAL.transaction_id)
  AND (BIGPDATAVIEW_TRANSACTION_HEADER.workstation_id = BIGPDATAVIEW_TRANSACTION_TOTAL.workstation_id))
INNER JOIN BIGPDATAVIEW_RETAIL_TRANSACTION_LINE_ITEM ON (BIGPDATAVIEW_RETAIL_TRANSACTION.location_id = BIGPDATAVIEW_RETAIL_TRANSACTION_LINE_ITEM.location_id)
AND (BIGPDATAVIEW_RETAIL_TRANSACTION.transaction_dt = BIGPDATAVIEW_RETAIL_TRANSACTION_LINE_ITEM.transaction_dt)
AND (BIGPDATAVIEW_RETAIL_TRANSACTION.transaction_id = BIGPDATAVIEW_RETAIL_TRANSACTION_LINE_ITEM.transaction_id)
AND (BIGPDATAVIEW_RETAIL_TRANSACTION.workstation_id = BIGPDATAVIEW_RETAIL_TRANSACTION_LINE_ITEM.workstation_id)
WHERE (((BIGPDATAVIEW_TRANSACTION_HEADER.transaction_type_cd)="1")
   AND ((BIGPDATAVIEW_TRANSACTION_HEADER.transaction_status_cd)="2")
   AND ((BIGPDATAVIEW_TRANSACTION_HEADER.location_id)=1430)
   AND ((BIGPDATAVIEW_TRANSACTION_HEADER.transaction_dt)=#12/20/2017#)
'This is the line you have to take out:
'AND ((BIGPDATAVIEW_TRANSACTION_HEADER.transaction_id)=5066)
   AND ((BIGPDATAVIEW_TRANSACTION_TOTAL.total_transaction_amt)>0
        AND (BIGPDATAVIEW_TRANSACTION_TOTAL.total_transaction_amt)<10)
   AND ((BIGPDATAVIEW_RETAIL_TRANSACTION.transaction_duration_nbr)>500) 
'This is the line you will need to put in:
    AND BIGPDATAVIEW_TRANSACTION_HEADER.transaction_id NOT IN(5066));
```

I added the 'Not In' condition to the end of he WHERE clause.  if you have another transaction in the future you want to exclude, you can put additional numbers in the parenthesis for that.  Such as:

```
NOT IN(5066, 5099, 3048)
```

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: That defiantly gets me closer to what I am trying to do, but is there a way I don't have to include a specific transaction number. I will be running data for 1400 stores and the data will have store 1-1400 with transactions linked to the specific store. I was hoping that it would work something like: If void_ind includes both Y and N exclude transaction_id                                                    Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: For clarity sake - your initial question was identifying a single transaction ID, your post asked to exclude 'this entire transaction'... but now your problem as i understand is a little different.

You will need to add a condition to exclude based on a subquery.

Answer (score 0):

For Example:
5206    20-Dec-17   8885    1   $8.40   906 N
5206    20-Dec-17   8885    1   $8.40   906 N
5206    20-Dec-17   8885    1   $8.40   906 N
5206    20-Dec-17   8885    1   $8.40   906 N
5195    20-Dec-17   209     3   $3.98   599 Y
5195    20-Dec-17   209     3   $3.98   599 N
5195    20-Dec-17   209     3   $3.98   599 N
5195    20-Dec-17   209     3   $3.98   599 N
5195    20-Dec-17   209     3   $3.98   599 N
5195    20-Dec-17   209     3   $3.98   599 N
5181    20-Dec-17   8689    2   $6.48   654 N
5181    20-Dec-17   8689    2   $6.48   654 N

My data needs to include store 5206 Transaction_id 8885 and store 5181 Transaction_id 8689. I need to exclude store 5195 and transaction 209 due to that it shows Y's and N's in the same transaction. Hopefully that is a better example of what my data looks like. This is just a sample of my data